# How to reorder all the vowels in a string?

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to create a method that reorders all the vowels in a string as efficiently as possible. For example:

`"you are incredible."` returns `"yae ere incridoblu."`

This is what I've come up with:

```
def vowel_orderer(string)
  vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
  ordered_vowels = string.scan(/[aeiou]/).sort
  ordered_string = []

  i = 0
  j = 0
  while i < string.length
    if vowels.include?(string[i])
      ordered_string << ordered_vowels[j]
      j += 1
    else
      ordered_string << string[i] unless vowels.include?(string[i])
    end
    i += 1
  end

  puts ordered_string.join

end
```

I feel like there should be a shorter way to accomplish this, using something like `gsub`?

Comment: Y is initially not a vowel but in the gym it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string = "you are incredible."
ordered_vowels = string.scan(/[aeiou]/).sort
string.gsub(/[aeiou]/){ordered_vowels.shift} # => "yae ere incridoblu."
```

Comment: hmm this didn't work when I plugged it in... can you explain?

Comment: Check again, it should be working. Basically you rely on fact that `gsub` iterates from the beginning and simply replaces first vowel in string with the first in the ordered array, second in string with second in the array etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
def vowel_orderer_gsub(string)
  ordered_vowels = string.scan(/[aeiou]/).sort { |x,y| y <=> x }
  puts string.gsub(/[aeiou]/) { |match| ordered_vowels.pop }
end

1.9.3p448 :128 >   vowel_orderer( "you are incredible." )
# yae ere incridoblu.
# => nil
1.9.3p448 :129 > vowel_orderer_gsub( "you are incredible." )
# yae ere incridoblu.
```